# Load distribution using Throughput controller in jmeter when throughput controller has child throughput controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, throughput

Please refer the attachment where i have mentioned the anticipated volume for each requests.

Had i not have Action 2 , I would have easily derived the load distribution.

I'm stuck when i have one more transaction inside the throughput controller **Action 1** . Can anyone please suggest what need to be the throughput controller value(%) when i still need to derive the load from that to the child request.

If i have addition of **Throughput Controller Search Action1** and **Throughput Controller Action 2** i end up having more volume for **Action 1**.

Hope my requirement is clear.Please can anyone suggest me how can i achieve the anticipated load for all the 4 requests.

[image: Jmeter Script with Anticipated Volume]

Comment: Don't quite get what you intend to do. Did you aim for 15 out of 32 (which, in turn is out of 210) for your Action 2 throughput controller?

Comment: yes ,end of the test i need to achieve 15 for Action 2.when i add all the transactions i need to have 210 as total sample count.Action 1 =32,Launch=34,Login 125.

Comment: Still not following you. If you need 15 of Action 2 AND 32 of Action 1 - why do you stack the 2 under the 1?

Comment: Not to mention that 125+34+32 doesn't make 210 with or without last 15.

Comment: please can you tell me what do you mean by "- why do you stack the 2 under the 1"... my action 2 is depending on action 1. and yes, action 2 should be 18 instead of 15 to make it total 210 :)my bad,still its fine for me if i come to know how to derive the load for action 2.

Comment: 19, not 18. 

210 - 125 - 32 - 34 = 19, that's elementary grade math

Comment: "my action 2 is depending on action 1" what kind of a dependence is there?

Comment: wish u know what throughput shaping timer does.

Comment: oh, man... here's the thing: the Throughput Controller is all BUT timer, if you make yourself bother to read at least little bit into documentation - you would immediately stumble upon red warning block: "This controller is badly named, as it does not control throughput. Please refer to the Constant Throughput Timer for an element that can be used to adjust the throughput."

Comment: now, again: what kind of a "dependency" you've got between Action 1 & Action 2?

Comment: Throughput shaping timer decides how many requests to fire per second (rps).
well there comes response time into picture.end of the test when you add all transactions executed, we achieve (rps*duration),not exactly but on an around.in action 1 i extract thr path for action2.

Comment: i got the solutio by R&D,ill update as an answer.

Comment: "in action 1 i extract thr path for action2"  - how do you match 15 (or 18, or 19 - whatever) to 32 then? how do you determine when to "extract thr path" and when not?

Comment: what does it matter if i extract or not? when i have throughput controller ?thats why we have throughput controller

Comment: when you particularly do not understand the question bcs it takes more than required explanation for you,there is no meaning in down voting the qsn. how i extract is left to me.If you have worked enough in designing the work load model, you would have atleast understood the question (answering is secondary) .

Comment: Wrong. That was you skipping your home work (you didn't even do the simple math!). Which makes you not understanding what YOU actually want to do by yourself. Which causes that you failed to explain what you need (no wonder, you don't understand it yourself). And on top of all that, you fall into denial & started to get aggressive. Each of that deserves -1, you're lucky that's only one available.

Comment: mate yes i dint give imp to the number 15 or 19.well thanks my maths teacher .i wont do this mistake again. would have been better if u had spent your precious time in getting the logic than proving what makes 210 complete

Answer (score 0):

You can go for something like:

[image]

If you need to execute these `15 times` samplers **after** `32 times` you can use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) in order to pause them until the data will be available.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]

Comment: Dmitri, Much respect for you replies.As you can see i decide the total anticipated volumes using Throughput shaping timer..hence 210 in total(0.35 per second)..34/210 is throughput controller Launch value.125/210 is logins throughput controllers value. but when it comes to action1 and action2 im stuck whether to have 15+32/210 as the % of execution(con:end up having more than 32 for action1) or only 32(wont achieve enough load for action2 and achieve more for lauch and login)

Answer (score -1):

In case you need to execute 32 Action 1 **with** 15 (or 18, or 19) of them followed by Action 2 - you have to put not one, but two Throughput controllers under under "Search action 32 of 210":

- first takes 19 "Action 1"s **followed by** "Action 1" out of 32
- second takes remaining 13 "Action 1" alone (not followed by "Action 2")

Is that what you are aiming for?

Answer (score -1):

Here Goes my Answer to my own question:

Like i said ,below is my Throughput shaping timer.

[image: Throughpu Shaping timer]

Virtual user is 3 because to perform 0.35 rps considering response time+think time as 10 sec (0.35RPS*10sec)

Below is the work load model :

[image: Work load model]

As launch and login is pretty clear , below is my explanation of action1 and action 2.

Since Out of 210 requests 51 requests(action 1 and action 2) should fall under one flow i need to have one thru controller as a parent which should make sure that out of 210 requests 51 should be from its child requests.Not over yet.

Now I cant let action 1 to take all 51 load because my req is 32. Hence i ll take 32 out of 51 requests for action 1.(32/52=62% of parent load)

Now for action 2 parent is action 1's load. so i need to make sure that when control comes (32 times) to action 1 i should let only 19 of them to proceed. hence 19/32 =59%.

Thus i achieved the desired load by making parent throughput controller to take responsibility of not letting other thoughput controller to take more than told load(launch and login) .

I have used Gaussian random timer value as 8 sec(2 sec deviation) when testing the actual application.

Comment: You would achieve the same with flat structure under your 51. All that endeavor was pretty ridiculous, I must admit. Lol.